# Does Camellia have a 256 bit block size?

Tags: cryptography

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_(cipher)) Camellia comes with a block size of 128 and a variable key size (128, 192, 256). [Another site](http://embeddedsw.net/Cipher_Reference_Home.html) lists it as a 256 Bit cipher.

The OpenSSL API has a function named `EVP_camellia_256_cbc`. Does this refer to the key size or the block size? And does Camellia support 256 Bit block sizes at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information on the Wikipedia page is correct: Camellia has a fixed block size of 128 bit and a variable key size of 128, 192 and 256 bit. You can compare that with other authoritative sources like its specification, e.g. found in [RFC 3713](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3713).

The "256 bit" in "256 bit cipher" usually refers to its security level and that is determined by its key size (and potential attack vectors that might decrease it).

Therefore, `EVP_camellia_256_cbc` means Camellia with a 256 bit key size, so you should supply keys of that size. Supplying keys of the correct key size is important, because some implementations may behave differently than others and you will lose a lot of time debugging when trying to connect different implementations.

For example, if you define that you want to use Camellia-256, but you're passing a key of 192 bit, it may happen that

- one implementation fills the passed key with 0x00 byte up to the specified key size,
- another implementation doesn't care about the specification and only looks at the actual supplied key to then run Camellia-192 or
- a broken implementation (for non-standard key sizes) that calculates the number of rounds (12 or 14 for Camellia) that need to be used and arrives at a non-standard number of rounds which makes the result non-compatible with all other implementations.